# Does the Keenness of the Stone Giant feat's Stone Throw receive the ability mod to damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, attack

Pretty straightforward question-- the Keenness of the Stone Giant grants the ability "Stone Throw":

> **Stone Throw.** As a bonus action, you can take a rock and make a magical attack with it. The attack is a ranged spell attack with a range of 60 feet that uses the ability score you increased with this feat as the spellcasting ability. On a hit, the rock deals 1d10 force damage, and the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw (DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + the spellcasting ability modifier) or have the prone condition. You can use this bonus action a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Since this is a ranged spell attack, can you add the modifier of the affected attribute to damage? For instance, if you raised your Con by 1 point with the feat, would you add your Con modifier to the damage of the Stone Throw?

Answer (score 5):

### No, you do not add your ability modifier to the damage

The feat says:

> **On a hit, the rock deals 1d10 force damage**, and the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw (DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + the spellcasting ability modifier) or have the prone condition.

There is no mention of an ability modifier, so you don't add any, you deal 1d10 force damage. This is entirely normal — you also do not add your spellcasting ability modifier or Dexterity as your ranged attacks modifier to the damage of other ranged spell attacks like *fire bolt*, unless they say so. Page 196, *PH*:

> When attacking with a **weapon**, you add your ability modifier—the same modifier used for the attack roll— to the damage. A **spell** tells you which dice to roll for damage and whether to add any modifiers.

And because this is a spell attack, not a weapon attack, throwing the stone does count as an attack with a spell, not with a weapon.